# Content not displaying on right side of vertical nav menu with nested sub-menu

Tags: bootstrap-4, submenu, nav-pills

Regarding bootstrap-4 nav menus, can someone please advise how to fix the nested submenus so the corresponding content - "Link button 1" "Link button 2" etc. - shows up to the right of the submenu instead of below the submenu?

```
<div class="container-fluid">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-sm-3">
                        <div class="nav flex-column nav-pills" id="pillnav" role="tablist" aria-orientation="vertical">
                            <a class="nav-link" id="pill1tab" data-toggle="pill" href="#pill1" role="tab" aria-controls="pill1" aria-selected="true">Pill 1</a>
                            <a class="nav-link" id="pill2tab" data-toggle="pill" href="#pill2" role="tab" aria-controls="pill2" aria-selected="false">Pill 2</a>                            
                        </div>
                    </div>                  
                    <div class="col-sm-9">
                        <div class="tab-content" id="pillcontent">
                            <div class="tab-pane fade" id="pill1" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="pill1tab">
                                
                                <div class="nav flex-column nav-pills" id="choice1nav" role="tablist" aria-orientation="vertical">
                                    <a class="nav-link" id="choice1-1tab" data-toggle="pill" href="#choice1-1" role="tab" aria-controls="choice1-1" aria-selected="true">Choice 1-1</a>
                                    <a class="nav-link" id="choice1-2tab" data-toggle="pill" href="#choice1-2" role="tab" aria-controls="choice1-2" aria-selected="false">Choice 1-2</a>    
                                </div>
                                <div class="tab-content" id="choice1content">
                                    <div class="tab-pane fade" id="choice1-1" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="choice1-1tab">Choice 1-1 content</div>
                                    <div class="tab-pane fade" id="choice1-2" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="choice1-2tab">Choice 1-2 content</div>
                                </div>
                                
                            </div>
                            <div class="tab-pane fade" id="pill2" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="pill2tab">                               
                                
                                <div class="nav flex-column nav-pills" id="choice2nav" role="tablist" aria-orientation="vertical">
                                    <a class="nav-link" id="choice2-1tab" data-toggle="pill" href="#choice2-1" role="tab" aria-controls="choice2-1" aria-selected="true">Choice 2-1</a>
                                    <a class="nav-link" id="choice2-2tab" data-toggle="pill" href="#choice2-2" role="tab" aria-controls="choice2-2" aria-selected="false">Choice 2-2</a>    
                                </div>
                                <div class="tab-content" id="choice1content">
                                    <div class="tab-pane fade" id="choice2-1" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="choice2-1tab">Choice 2-1 content</div>
                                    <div class="tab-pane fade" id="choice2-2" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="choice2-2tab">Choice 2-2 content</div>
                                </div>                              
                                
                            </div>                          
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Comment: Is it on the right --> https://codeply.com/p/PivPrLnXJg

Comment: The sub-menu is on the right, but the content of the sub-menu "Link button 1", etc. displays below the sub-menu instead of to the right. Editing original question for clarity.